# List both parent entry and its child entry

Tags: children, parents, craft.entries

I am trying to display a list of entries.  Specifically the parent entry and it's children's entry.

I started off using this:

```
{% nav page in craft.entries.section('forms').isChildOf.slug('applicant-form') %}

    <li>
        {{ page.getLink() }}

        {% ifchildren %}
            <ul>{% children %}</ul>
        {% endifchildren %}
    </li>

{% endnav %}
```

But this only displays the Parent.

I found this solution on Stack here, and all the children display but not the parent.  I also wonder if this is the best solution to display the children as it seems a bit more lines than what is in the Craft docs.

Many thanks.

```
{% set topLevel = (entry.level == 1) ? entry : entry.getAncestors().level(1).first()  %}

{% if topLevel.hasDescendants %}

    <ul>
        {% set nav =  topLevel.getDescendants()  %}

        {% nav page in nav  %}
            {% if page.id != entry.id %}
                <li>{{ page.getLink() }}</li>
            {%else%}
                <li>{{page}}</li>
            {%endif%}

        {% ifchildren %}
            <ul>
                {% children %}
            </ul>
        {% endifchildren %}

        {% endnav %}

    </ul>

{% endif %}
```

Comment: I think I have managed to fix this, to include the missing Parent I just add in the in  {{ entry.title }}

Comment: Would you mind adding what worked for you as an official answer? Might end up helping someone in the future! :)

Comment: Hi @BradBell, that's done - had to wait to answer my own question.

Answer (score 1):

This is the corrected Twig code. I simply added `{{ entry.title }}` as an `<li>` item. This nav appears only on the page that I needed `entry.title` displaying.

```
{% set navList = (entry.level == 2) ? entry : entry.getAncestors().level(2).first()  %}

{% if navList.hasDescendants %}

    <ul>
        {% set nav =  navList.getDescendants()  %}
        <li>{{ entry.title }}</li>
        {% nav page in nav  %}
            {% if page.id != entry.id %}
                <li>{{ page.getLink() }}</li>
            {% else %}
                <li>{{page}}</li>
            {% endif %}
        {% ifchildren %}
            <ul>
                {% children %}
            </ul>
        {% endifchildren %}
        {% endnav %}
    </ul>

{% endif %}
```